# X.org driver performs the best but cannot make the 2nd monitor work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have problems working with multiple monitors on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

```
Relevant specs of my laptop:

-i7-9750H

-nvidia RTX 2060M (6GB)
```

I am not a veteran Ubuntu user but I must use Ubuntu for my new project now which will take a few months so I am trying to make the transition from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. Unfortunately I am so used to work with a secondary monitor, I just cannot live without it.

If I use nvidia's proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-450/460) the second monitor works just fine but there's noticeable input lag during general use(even higher on GeForce Now) and screen tearing in the secondary monitor watching videos (Netflix).

On the other hand if I use X.org driver the problems mentioned above are bearably solved, but the second monitor won't work. The second monitor will sometimes show the background image, it will sometimes show a black screen - it will always show the cursor accordingly, but it will not show anything else. If I move a screen from the main screen to the secondary screen, I'll see my cursor but I won't see the window that I am moving in the second screen. All I will see is a window on the main screen that is slowly disappearing into oblivion by being pushed over the edge of the screen off to the world eating secondary display.

No matter which one I try it's never as smooth as Windows but X.org driver is definitely usable compared to my experience with proprietary nvidia drivers.

Do anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Best

Comment: How do you connect your display? By DP?

Comment: I connect it via HDMI.

Comment: Try this command: `randr --output HDMI-1-0  --right-of eDP --mode 1920x1080`